# How do i use svg animation from codepen in my site?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, codepen

I want to use these kinds os svg animation
in my site how can i import this in my website.
I tried creating the HTML, CSS, and javascript provided in that page and added the link and script appropriately still it is not working. [link to code pen](https://codepen.io/miguelcast/pen/pwZMOJ)
i also tried to embed like this

```
<p data-height="265" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="pwZMOJ" data-default-tab="css,result" data-user="miguelcast" data-embed-version="2" data-pen-title="Social Icons vision 3D" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="https://codepen.io/miguelcast/pen/pwZMOJ/">Social Icons vision 3D</a> by Miguel Cast (<a href="https://codepen.io/miguelcast">@miguelcast</a>) on <a href="https://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
```

Comment: What happens if you embed it with that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats using **SCSS (SASS)** You need to convert to CSS then it works.

```css
.flex-center {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 50vh;
  background: #000;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.icon-3d {
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-animation: icon3d 200ms 10;
  animation: icon3d 200ms 10;
  color: #fff;
}
.icon-3d:hover {
  -webkit-animation: icon3d 200ms infinite;
  animation: icon3d 200ms infinite;
}

@keyframes icon3d {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 5px 4px #f44336, -5px -6px #2196f3;
  }
  25% {
    text-shadow: -5px -6px #f44336, 5px 4px #2196f3;
  }
  50% {
    text-shadow: 5px -4px #f44336, -8px 4px #2196f3;
  }
  75% {
    text-shadow: -8px -4px #f44336, -5px -4px #2196f3;
  }
  100% {
    text-shadow: -5px 0 #f44336, 5px -4px #2196f3;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex-center">
  <i class="fa fa-github fa-4x icon-3d"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-gitlab fa-4x icon-3d"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-bitbucket fa-4x icon-3d"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-git fa-4x icon-3d"></i>
</div>

<div class="flex-center">
  <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-4x icon-3d"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-4x icon-3d"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-4x icon-3d"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-whatsapp fa-4x icon-3d"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah it worked, So you have to just convert the scss to css thats it?

Comment: I also trid this one https://codepen.io/chrisgannon/pen/OmpPPv i guess it is not using scss then why this isn't working??

Comment: it has external javascripts. you can click on settings and see what is being used externally.

Comment: `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js` and `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/16327/CustomEase.min.js`